# SQL calculate time difference with previous row

Tags: sql, calculated-field

I have code that provides the order number, the estimated time of delivery, the actual time of delivery and the difference between the two times.

If the order is late I need to take that difference and add it to the next order to display the new estimated time of delivery.

How can I have SQL reach back to the previous row and get the calculated difference to add to the estimated time of delivery? LAG is not available since we are using 2012 SQL Shell.

Comment: do you mind sharing some data and code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets the datediff of current datetime from previous record

```
WITH orders AS
(SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datetimecolumn) AS rownum
   FROM  mytable
)

SELECT DATEDIFF(second, curr.est_tod, prev.act_tod)
  FROM orders curr
 INNER JOIN orders prev
    ON curr.rownum = prev.rownum - 1
```

Comment: ON mc.rownum = mp.rownum - 1

Comment: the multipart identifier could not be bound